# If $x = 2$ is a root of $\det\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x&-6&-1\\2&-3x&x-3\\-3&2x&x+2\end{smallmatrix}\right]=0$, find other two roots

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

> If $x = 2$ is a root of equation 
>   $$ \begin{vmatrix}
> x & -6 & -1 \\
> 2 & -3x & x-3\\
> -3 & 2x & x+2 
> \end{vmatrix} = 0 $$
>   Then find the other two roots.

I solved it and got a cubic equation, and then I divided it by $(x-2)$ to get the other two roots. But this is a long method to do.

Please help me with some shorter approach to this question.

Comment: Subtract the 2nd row from the 1st row and factor out the $x-2$.

Comment: Yes it worked, you can post it as an answer @Yuta

Comment: The determinant is equal to $0$ iff there is a row (or column) $R_i$ such that it is linearly dependent on another row (or column) i.e. $R_i=\lambda R_j$

Comment: @FareedAF Not exactly. You can have all three rows be linearly dependent without there being any row which is a multiple of another.

Comment: Oh ok @Arthur  but if there is 2 rows such that $R_i=\lambda R_j$ then the determinant will be zero right? I mean the word "linearly dependent" was my mistake is that true?

Comment: @FareedAF: "iff" was your mistake.

Comment: Thank you @Cheerful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
x & -6 & -1 \\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix} & =  
\begin{vmatrix}
x-2 & 3x-6 & 2-x \\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& = (x-2)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& = (x-2)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -3x-6 & x-1\\
-3 & 2x+9 & x-1 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& = (x-2)(x-1)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -3x-6 & 1\\
-3 & 2x+9 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& = (x-2)(x-1)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & -5x-15 & 0\\
-3 & 2x+9 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& = (x-2)(x-1)(-5x-15) \\
& = -5(x-2)(x-1)(x+3) \\
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, the other roots are $1$ and $-3$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{vmatrix}
x & -6 & -1 \\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$

$\begin{vmatrix}
x-2 & 3x-6 & 2-x\\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$
$R_1 \rightarrow R_1-R_2$

$(x-2)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & -1\\
2 & -3x & x-3\\
-3 & 2x & x+2 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$
$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & -1\\
0 & -3x-6 & x-1\\
0 & 2x+9 & x-1
\end{vmatrix} = 0$
$R_2 \rightarrow R_2-2R_1$,
$R_3 \rightarrow R_3+3R_1$

Now open the determinant using $C_1$
 clearly,one factor is (x-1). You get -3x-6= 2x+9, x=-3.